# How to fire a second function after a triggering a function in a functional component (React, React Hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a button:

```
<button onClick={doSomething}>Do it</button>
```

And I have a function

```
const doSomething = () => {
  console.log(1)
}
```

And I want `console.log(2)` to fire after triggering `doSomething`.

Something like this:

```
const doSomething = () => {
  console.log(1)
  console.log(2)
}
```

But this one fires `console.log(2)` immediately. What I want is to fire `console.log(2)` after `console.log(1)`, when clicking on the button.

Do I need to use `useEffect()` here? If yes, how?

**EDIT**:

Here is the problem. `getQuestions()` fires immediately when the function `a` runs. I want `getQuestions()` to fire after `props.answerQuestion()` finished.

```
   const a = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        props.answerQuestion({
            question: question,
            answer: answer,
        });

        getQuestions();
    };
```

**EDIT2:**

```
export const answerQuestion = (answerQuestion) => (dispatch) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token) {
        axios
            .post("http://localhost:5000/answerQuestion", answerQuestion, {
                headers: {
                    "X-Auth-Token": token,
                },
            })
            .then((res) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: ANSWER_QUESTION,
                    payload: res.data,
                });
            });
    }
};
```

Comment: You might have to clarify this: `But this one fires console.log(2) immediately. What I want is to fire console.log(2) after console.log(1),`

Comment: Yes, use an effect hook to run an effect *after* a value in its dependency array updates. My intuition is your use case isn't simple console logging, this may be too over simplified. Please update question with actual code and issue.

Comment: what wrong with the function in which you log both? its  seems fine to me.

Comment: you could make your function async and await each individual call, or use a promise chain, but i'm unsure what problem you're trying to solve here. why not simply call the functions one after another if they're synchronous?

Comment: I edited the question to be more specific

Comment: it sounds like your `answerQuestion` function is async in some capacity, so you'd want to run `useEffect(() => getQuestions(), [???]);` when your component re-renders, based on whatever prop(s) and/or internal state object(s) change after `answerQuestion` finishes resolving behind the scenes.

Comment: @David does `props.answerQuestion` return a promise? or can you show us what that function looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `JavaScript Promises` for this problem. Using `Promises` in `answerQuestion()` Function will let you use to chain `.then()` and `.catch()` method in `a function`

```
export const answerQuestion = (answerQuestion) => (dispatch) => return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token) {
        axios
            .post("http://localhost:5000/answerQuestion", answerQuestion, {
                headers: {
                    "X-Auth-Token": token,
                },
            })
            .then((res) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: ANSWER_QUESTION,
                    payload: res.data,
                });
                resolve();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
             })
    }
});
```

```
const a = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        props.answerQuestion({
            question: question,
            answer: answer,
        })
        .then(() => {
            getQuestions();
         })
         .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
          })

        
    };
```

Comment: this one seems to be working but `return` had a red underline so I had to remove it

Comment: sorry typed ```return``` by mistake.

Comment: Don't use the Promise antipattern. Just `return axios.post...`. And especially don't create Promises that may never settle. This ensures that everything that depends on this promise will never finish and the memory will never be released. Not untill you close the tab.

Comment: However you can cancel the promise if it’s not resolve after some specific time limit.   Your point is also valid

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't need to use `useEffect` in this scenario, all you want to do is wait for the api call to resolve before calling `getQuestions`. one way you can accomplish this is by:

```
// update answerQuestion into an async function
export const answerQuestion = async (answerQuestion) => async (dispatch) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token) {
        const response = await axios // <--- add await here
            .post("http://localhost:5000/answerQuestion", answerQuestion, {
                headers: {
                    "X-Auth-Token": token,
                },
            })
        await dispatch({
            type: ANSWER_QUESTION,
            payload: response.data,
        });
    }
};
```

then in your component:

```
   const a = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        await props.answerQuestion({
            question: question,
            answer: answer,
        });

        getQuestions();
    };
```